# Avoid calling a non-virtual method in a unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm tasked with writing some tests to one of our codebases.
Now I have this class:

```

```
public class A 
{
  public void method_1() 
  { 
    this.method_2();
    // Do something
  }

  public void method_2() 
  {
     Environment.CurrentDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
     // Do something
  }
}
```

```

Now I'm trying to write a test for method_1 without invoking method_2 and getting `NullReferenceException`.

```
[TestClass]
public class MyTestClass
{

  [TestMethod]
  public void MyTestMethod()
  {
    // Ignore the call: Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() because it returns null>

    new A().method_1();
  }
```

Any suggestion?

**EDIT**:
I'm not allowed to change the code.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to mock / shim Assembly?

Comment: One proper way to do it you would be to extract the part that is file-system dependent, create an interface for it, and inject in class A as dependency, in constructor. Then, in the tests, you can safely inject a Mock<theInterface> that will just do nothing, or simulate results (or errors) from filesystem.

Comment: Does the method_1() or method_2() changes the object state (ex. some field or property you can observe) ?

Comment: @Pac0 Unfortunately, I can't change the code. I guess the use of mocking is necessary, I just don't how to implement it in this case without virtual methods.

Answer (score 2):

Without the possibility to override/mock the logic inside `method_2` there is not much you can do.
If it is your own codebase I suggest to move the call to `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location` to some helper method which you can override for the tests.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you cannot change anything to the code, you can use [MS Fakes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh549175.aspx) to mock out static methods like DateTime.Now. Should also work on Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().

---

I'm not a big fan of MS Fakes though, had a few too many problems with it in the past. If you can make a small change to the code, you can make the method_2 virtual and do something like this:

```
public class MyTestA : A 
{
  public override void method_2() 
  {
    //Do nothing
  }
}
```

You can then write your tests against MyTestA.

Of course, putting the code in method 2 in a new class/interface and mock that as a dummy interface is an even cleaner solution.